# Task Parallelism Open MP (C Language)

Tags: c, recursion, openmp, pragma

I have a problem with making from the sequential algorithm parallel one with task parallelism.

My problem is the Minimum Cut of a Graph and in sequential case, I can achieve the correct result.

Here is part of my code:

**main.c**

```
struct ProblemInstance instance = readFromFile(file);

    bool *solution = malloc(sizeof(bool) * vertexCount);

    for (int n = 0; n < vertexCount; n++) 
        solution[n] = false;

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        printf("Number of thread: %d \n", omp_get_thread_num());
        #pragma omp single
        recursiveBruteForce(solution, 0, 0);
    }
```

**problem.c**

```
void recursiveBruteForce(bool *solution, float cutSum, int depth) {

    // In case if it is not correct
    if (checkPartialSolution(solution, depth)) return;
    if (cutSum > minCutValue) return;

    if (depth == vertexCount) {
        minCutValue = cutSum;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
            minCutArray[i] = solution[i];
        return;
    }

    solution[depth] = false;

    #pragma omp task
    recursiveBruteForce(solution, minCutSum(solution, depth + 1), depth + 1);

    solution[depth] = true;

    #pragma omp task
    recursiveBruteForce(solution, minCutSum(solution, depth + 1), depth + 1);
}

// Check Particular Solution to how many 1 and 0 have
bool checkPartialSolution(const bool *solution, int depth) {
    int a = 0, n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        if (solution[i]) 
          a = a + 1;
        else 
          n = n + 1;

        if (a > subgroupSize || n > (vertexCount - subgroupSize)) 
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Get a sum of Sub-Graph
double minCutSum(const bool *solution, int depth) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (solution[j] != solution[i])
                sum += graphConnections[j][i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I have tried to look at how many calls did *recursiveBruteForce*  function. In sequential, it is approximately 22,000, while in parallel 62. I think the problem with memory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to confirm, is your problem that you aren't able to parallelize the code properly?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to see expected input and output. And what exactly goes wrong in the parallel case

Comment: You have shared variables which have racy accesses to them (solution, minCutValue)...

Comment: @Warpstar22 Yes. I cannot parallelize properly. Here is the full code: https://github.com/siftoshka/MIE-PDP

Comment: @JimCownie I have tried also to do them private, but it also stucks after some function calls

Comment: @Warpstar22 the input file is in cmake-buld-debug -> mhr_20_10_5.txt. First 3 are: 20(integer number representing the number of nodes of the graph), 10(small integer number representing average node degree of the graph), 5(integer number). And then is properties of the graph: {source} {destination} {weight}. The output is a sum of all weights that form the minimum cut. In my case, it is 14.612 (It can be reachable with 1 thread)

Comment: @siftoshka making the variables private won't work because you obviously need to share data. There are also critical and atomic options to prevent data races.

Comment: @Warpstar22 I know about critical and atomic. But I can't figure out where should I use it. All my attempts were fail. Could you help me please?